# How to chain methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I need to do many methods on `lnk.href` to get the `f_name`.
I want to write the code that way, but it gave me

```
undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If I don't want to write these in one line (as it's hard to read), what's a better way in Ruby?

```
f_name = lnk.href.split('/').last
         .gsub!(/[(]+/, "_")
         .gsub!(/[)]+/, "_")
```

Answer (score 6):

[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` if there's no match:

```
'1'.gsub!(/2/, '_')
# => nil
'1'.gsub!(/2/, '_').gsub!(/1/, '_')
# NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass
#         from (irb):6
#         from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Replace `gsub!` with `gsub` will probably solve your problem:

```
'1'.gsub(/2/, '_')
# => "1"
'1'.gsub(/2/, '_').gsub(/1/, '_')
# => "_"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to the syntax but only because some methods return `nil` in your case.

Comment: Or `gsub!` returned `nil` in case so substitutions were performed.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you are trying to write some of the methods you want to chain on a new line to make it more readable? You can't break a method call down to  a new line all by itself, as you've discovered, since now Ruby thinks you are trying to call a method on nothing.

I'm operating on the assumption that what you are trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
lnk = <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620460/how-to-chain-methods-in-ruby">Some Link</a>

f_name = lnk.href.split('/').last.gsub!(/[(]+/, "_").gsub!(/[)]+/, "_")
```

So, you're trying to find and break up links in HTML by splitting them at the `/`, then pulling out and manipulating the last part of the URL.

There are a couple things you can do to make this more readable and logical. One is to fix your regex. Because you're using [`.gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), you are already searching for all matching occurrences, so the `+` is unnecessary. You can also combine your two calls to `.gsub!` into one like this: `.gsub!(/[()]/, "_")`

That will match and substitute all occurrences of either the open or close paren, making your chain one method shorter.

For the rest, I would suggest breaking this into two steps at the logical place: between creating a data structure, and manipulating the data within it. First, create the array of substrings:

```
f_name = lnk.href.split('/')
```

Then manipulate the data from that array:

```
manipulated_substring = f_name.last.gsub!(/[()]/, "_")
```

That will make your code more readable, and keep your data intact!